# pandas dataframe filter a Object column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need your lights!
I have  a dataframe build by this code:

```
import itertools as ite
import pandas as pd

items=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
data = [200,250,190,0,132,149,168,0,198,184,176,203]

result=[(combi,len(da),sum(da),min(da),max(da)) 
        for nbCombi in range(5,10) 
               for combi,da in zip(ite.combinations(items, nbCombi),ite.combinations(data, nbCombi))]

df=pd.DataFrame(result,columns=["Combinaison","Nb","Poids","Min","Max"])
df['Ecart']=df['Min']-df['Max']
```

That give me thousands results but one of these ones could be for example:

```
Combinaison               Nb     Poids     Min     Max    Ecart   
(1, 2, 5, 6, 10, 11)      6      942        0      250     250
```

The dtypes of the combinaison column is object. Is it an array?

How can I Filter the result in order to exclude the combinations found with the item 1 or 5 for example?
I know how to filter a dataframe on integer column but I don't know how to do when the type is an array or an object.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use filtering using apply:

```
df[df.Combinaison.apply(lambda val: not any([i in val for i in [1,5]]))]
```

Edit: In general, it might be better to put each value of the tuple into a column. I assume you're keeping it as a tuple for some other reason though.

Edit 2: My original solution had used an additional lambda that was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use use apply with np.in1d to check if both or any of one element is preset in the Combinaison column i.e

```
import numpy as np
df[~df.Combinaison.apply(lambda x : any(np.in1d([1,5],np.array(x))))]
```

Output:

```
          Combinaison  Nb  Poids  Min  Max  Ecart
337   (2, 3, 4, 6, 7)   5    757    0  250   -250
338   (2, 3, 4, 6, 8)   5    589    0  250   -250
339   (2, 3, 4, 6, 9)   5    787    0  250   -250
340  (2, 3, 4, 6, 10)   5    773    0  250   -250
341  (2, 3, 4, 6, 11)   5    765    0  250   -250
```

To filter `Combinaison` with both 1,5 present use `all` instead of `any`.